# Find out how many requests to the Google URL shortener API are from Codecademy users

Tags: javascript, api, xmlhttprequest

Context: On Codecademy, there is an [exercise under the Requests section in the Learn JavaScript course](https://www.codecademy.com/courses/intermediate-javascript-requests/lessons/requests-i/exercises/xhr-post-requests-iii?action=resume_content_item&course_redirect=introduction-to-javascript). This exercise teaches how to write `POST` requests using AJAX with the `XMLHttpRequest` object. We practice by creating a webpage that allows users to submit a link and it `POST`s the link to the [Google URL shortener API](https://developers.google.com/url-shortener/) and returns the shortened URL.

My question is: Is there a way to find out from the Google URL shortener API, how many `POST` requests are made from Codecademy users? How much of the traffic is from Codecademy? Is this public data? It would be funny if something like a tenth of requests to the shortener were from this one JS course.

Sorry if my wording or question is rookie, but I am having trouble learning about APIs even 1 year into JS programming. Thank you for reading my question and I hope you can take a minute to write an answer if you have one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems to this...

First of all, you'd need to be able to identify a Codecademy user. Here are a few options:

- Use the IP address, but seeing as it's an online course, all the users would be distributed.
- Use the requested URL to shorten - this would work, but Google doesn't have an API to tell you how many people and what URL's have been requested to shorten (for business and privacy reasons)
- Use the API token, if the sample available on the website has a user/auth token, then Google would know how many requests used that token, but again this information is a business secret and wouldn't be exposed to the end user.

Now, if you were an ISP and the requests to Google URL shortener were in plain HTTP, then you could simply read the requests and keep track of any of the previous identifying information as the requests bounce across your router network.

If you were Google, you'd also have access to that information.

If you were Codecademy, you would know how many people accessed that webpage/tutorial and w/ a rough guess (ie. 10% of users actually run the tutorial) you could guess the usage as some percentage of the number of users that accessed the tutorial.

As just another person on the internet, you have no access to Google's server logs, the ISPs' (multiple of them!) router/DNS network logs or Codecademy's website traffic information. Also, an API like this would be used for monitoring, metrics and billing purposes on Google's end.

p.s. Google's closing down their URL shortening service soon, so their metrics either shows that no one is using it, or that maybe they're paying too much to handle url rerouting for other people. Source: https://www.theverge.com/2018/3/31/17184164/google-alphabet-url-shortening-service-closed